# Cross origin error thrown on GraphQL subscription

Tags: reactjs, graphql, hasura, graphql-subscriptions, cors-anywhere

I'm setting up GraphQL subscription as per this tutorial: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/guides/integrations/apollo-subscriptions.html

I'm getting CORS error and all my requests to web sockets are failed. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasura uses a special way for dealing with CORS, depending on which environment you are using.
If you are using heroku, in your env variables you need to add Hasura specific variables to enable CORS.

```
HASURA_GRAPHQL_CORS_DOMAIN="https://*.foo.bar.com:8080, http://*.localhost, http://localhost:3000, http://example.com"
```

Check out the [CORS configuration example](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/deployment/graphql-engine-flags/config-examples.html#configure-cors)

Comment: I'm using Heroku. Where can I add these variables?

Comment: In your Heroku Dashboard - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars - might help.